# Unable to establish client - server connection in my network

Tags: python

i used  a basic python client and server script to emulate client and server example in my network .
In the server side i ran this script :

```
# UDP server example
import socket
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
server_socket.bind(("", 5000))
print"UDPServer Waiting for client on port 5000"
while 1:
 data, address = server_socket.recvfrom(256)
 print "( " ,address[0], " " , address[1] , " ) said : ", data
```

and ran the client script in another system :

```
# UDP client example
import socket
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
while 1:
 data = raw_input("Type something(q or Q to exit): ")
 if (data <> 'q' and data <> 'Q'):
     client_socket.sendto(data, ("localhost",5000))
 else:
     break
client_socket.close()
```

in the client script instead of localhost i wrote the IP of my server system .  still no signs of connection . Is something i am doing wrong in here ?

Comment: Your code works for me. Do you have some kind of internet firewall active? Also, does it work for you if you use "localhost"?

Comment: it works if i run both the script in the same system , but i am executing the code in different system. do i have to do ne changes to make it work.

Comment: I tried it on two different machines here and it worked fine. The only part I changed was "localhost" to my actual server address.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with the first comment.  This sounds like a firewall issue.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you run it on some kind of *nix.
You might want to run

```
iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 5000 -j ACCEPT
```

to open the firewall for port 5000.